# How Can I record a short video in an Android app?

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture

I am developing an application where I press a button and it will record a 10 second video and store it in internal storage. How can I do that?

Comment: FYI Android Studio is an IDE. You record no videos with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **Intent** you can do this.

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE_VEDIO);
}
```

in `onActivityResult` method

```
Uri videoUri = data.getData();
path = Utils.getRealPathFromURI(videoUri, this);
manageVideo(path); //Do whatever you want with your video
```